# Присвоить ключ мултикурл многопоточный парсер

Tags: curl, php, mysql

Есть скрипт многопоточного парсера на Curle. Он перебирает массив со ссылками

```
$urls = array('google.ru', 'yandex.ru', и тд);
$chs = array();
foreach($urls as $url) {
    $chs[] = ($ch = curl_init());

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_multi_add_handle($mh, $ch);
}

$prev_running = $running = null;

do {
    curl_multi_exec($mh, $running);
    if ($running != $prev_running) {
        $info = curl_multi_info_read($mh);

        if (is_array($info) && ($ch = $info['handle'])) {

            $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
            // получаю содержимое загруженной страницы
            $content = curl_multi_getcontent($ch);

            echo 'Прошло '.$info['total_time'].
            ' секунд во время запроса к '.$info['url'].
            "<br>";

        }
        // обновляю кешируемое число текущих активных соединений
        $prev_running = $running;
    }

} while ($running > 0);
foreach($chs as $ch) {
    curl_multi_remove_handle($mh, $ch);
    curl_close($ch);
}
curl_multi_close($mh);
```

Единственный ключ на выходе который я могу получить это сама ссылка.

Какие есть варианты присвоения дополнительного ключа массиву? Ссылки берутся из базы т.е ID and Name всё есть, а как использовать?